# How to take a photo similar to an old photo?

Tags: applications, camera

Is there any app to help take a photo similar to an older photo of the same building/view? like in the past winter or summer.

I am thinking of an app that shows the old photo on screen a little bit transparent, so I can adjust the position of camera and take an identical photo.

Searching didn't help. Thanks.